# Widget ListView: How to make space between items

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hi. How to make space between items in Listview. I've tried changing Column mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, to MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween and tried adding padding to the ListView but still no change. Is there anyone who can give an opinion on how to make space between ListView items.

```
Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: _appointmentList.isNotEmpty ? 20 : 0),
                      _appointmentList.isNotEmpty
                          ? Row(
                              children: [
                                const Text(
                                  "Appointment",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      height: 1.4,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) => AppointmentList(
                                                    token: widget.token,
                                                    userUID: widget.userUID,
                                                    apiEndPoint: widget.apiEndPoint,
                                                  )),
                                        );
                                      },
                                      child: const Text("View all",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 16,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                              color: Color(0xFF0E71B0))),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                          : Container(),
                      SizedBox(height: _appointmentList.isNotEmpty ? 15 : 0),
                      _appointmentList.isNotEmpty
                          ? Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 240,
                                  child: ListView(
                                    //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                  
                                    children: _appointmentList
                                        .map((item) =>
                                            item.doctorProfile.uid == doctor["UID"]
                                                ? appointmentBox(
                                                    context, item, widget.token)
                                                : Container())
                                        .toList()
                                        .cast<Widget>(),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                          : Container(),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => MakeAnAppointment(
                                      doctor: doctor,
                                      token: widget.token,
                                      userUID: widget.userUID,
                                      apiEndPoint: widget.apiEndPoint,
                                    )),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 12, horizontal: 20),
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFF0E71B0),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                "assets/icons/calendar_plus_icon.svg",
                                color: Colors.white,
                                matchTextDirection: true,
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 5),
                              const Text(
                                "Make an appointment",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try wrapping appointmentBox with Padding:

```
Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: appointmentBox(context, item, widget.token),
          )
```